# Loading texture by tiles in three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm creating a 3d world map in three.js and for better quality and precision I'd like to load the texture by tiles dependent on current zoom level.

I'd like to achieve something similar as [this](http://examples.webglearth.com/#helloworld) but in three.js.

Currently I have one big texture, see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bvzx7z2h/).

```
var mesh = THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, segments, segments),
        new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
            map:         THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/turban/webgl-earth/master/images/2_no_clouds_4k.jpg'),
            bumpScale:   0.005,
            specular:    new THREE.Color('grey')                                
        })
    );
```

But I'd like to request the texture in tiles from [here](http://otile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/4/5/7.jpg).

Are there any similar solutions done in three.js or does anyone know how can I stitch the texture from tiles.

Comment: Hi, have you found any usable solution? I'm also looking for something like that in ThreeJS. There is a lot of frameworks but no one that use ThreeJS.

Comment: Hi sorry have not found anything useful.

Comment: For future reference found something similar here http://potree.org/demo/experimental/2015.08.19_cesium_test/examples/cesium_test.html

Comment: BabylonJS has a nice MultiMaterial tiled mesh: http://makina-corpus.com/blog/metier/2014/how-to-use-multimaterials-with-a-tiled-ground-in-babylonjs